# PHP Zip extension in xampp for windows

Tags: php, windows, apache, zip, xampp

I'm using latest xampp(v3.1.0) in my windows system. I want to use zip extension. How can I enable it? I've heard that it's already pre-compiled in latest xampp. I've already taken a look at *php.ini* but there is no extension related to zip neither in extension folder.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.2.0 and later has inbuilt zip function just have to active the zip library.

```
 Windows users need to enable php_zip.dll inside of 
 php.ini in order to use these functions.
```